# Trying to make a trap

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a trap but when I execute the command below I get:

> The dataTag does not match eb191f00-3ec9-4ebd-bfbf-ba980ded6

even if I change id to `minecraft:redstone_torch`

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add trap {Item:{id:"redstone_torch",OnGround:1b}}

execute @e[tag=trap] ~ ~ ~ summon armor_stand ~ ~-1.9 ~ {Tags:["trapPrime"],Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"stone",Count:1b,tag{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"trap_display"}}}]}

kill @e[tag=trap]
```

Comment: You have to give more details. All we know from this is that there is at least one item in the world that is not a redstone torch in the ground.

Comment: its cause the first bit which isn't working is suppose to be in the first command block/first part of function

Comment: As @Fabian said, we need more detail.  How is the trap supposed to work?  Is a player supposed to knock a torch off the wall and that triggers the trap?  Is that trap supposed to kill the player that triggers it?

Comment: this is simply to set the trap when you throw down the "torch" it's suppose to set itself 1.9 into the block letting the top be seen {video of what should happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHoGGA5NQhg) even if i copy what he does get same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scoreboard tag command has `OnGround:1b` inside of `Item:{...}` it needs to be outside those brackets like this:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item,tag=!trap] add trap {Item:{id:"minecraft:redstone_torch"},OnGround:1b}
```

Also, your execute/summon command is missing `:` at `tag{Unbreakable`.  Here is the corrected command:

```
execute @e[tag=trap] ~ ~ ~ summon armor_stand ~ ~-1.9 ~ {Tags:["trapPrime"],Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"stone",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"trap_display"}}}]}
```

With those fixed, you throw a redstone torch and get:

[image: Stone]

Comment: I'm glad you have a solution to your problem.  One recommendation, if you ask another question, add more detail to the question.  In this case, until you added that video in your comment, no one knew what you were asking.  If people don't know what you are asking, they can't give you an answer.